# access application context within @Endpoint Spring WS 1.5

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

I would like to access beans that i have defined in /WEB-INF/springws-servlet.xml from within my Endpoint handler method. Currently I am resorting to as shown below. Is there a better way to access the context to get the bean within the Endpoint.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("webapp/WEB-INF/springws-servlet.xml");

BeanType mybean = (BeanType) ctx.getBean("mybean");
```

Same thing with the jaxb2marshaller. I have it setup in the springws-servlet.xml. How do I access it in my Endpoint instead of doing

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.test.mypackage");
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
```

Below is my webapp/WEB-INF/springws-servlet.xmlwebapp/WEB-INF/springws-servlet.xml

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbmarshaller"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="endpointMapping" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping"/>


  <bean id="jaxbmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>org.hr_xml._3.SyncHRMasterDataType</value>
            <value>org.openapplications.oagis._9.ConfirmBODType</value>
        </list>
    </property>
  </bean>



  <bean id="mybean" class="com.test.package">
    <property name="releaseID" value="1"/>
  </bean>
```

thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just autowire in your dependency within the endpoint:

```
class MyEndPoint{

  @Autowired MyBean mybean
..
}
```

Comment: When using annotations to inject beans you should take a look at the [@Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) classes in Spring as well! That'd simplify this even more.